# Are sober noetherian spaces sequential?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, noetherian, first-countable

A sequential topological space $X$ has a few different equivalent definitions:

1. $X$ is the quotient of a first-countable space
2. $X$ is the quotient of a metric space
3. Sequentially open subsets of $X$ are open
4. Sequentially closed subsets of $X$ are closed
5. For every subset of $X$ that is not closed, there is a convergent sequence to a point outside the subset
6. Any sequentially continuous function from $X$ to another space is continuous
7. The topology is the final topology with regards to all continuous maps from the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{N}$, i.e. convergent sequences in $X$, so those generate the topology

[The Wikipedia article on sequential spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space#Examples_and_sufficient_conditions) claims that the spectrum of any noetherian ring is sequential.  It does not provide a reference for this, is there one? Alternatively, is there a short proof of this statement? The most straightforward translation to a purely topological statement would be whether sober noetherian spaces are sequential.

Comment: [This reference](http://topology.nipissingu.ca/tp/reprints/v28/tp28210.pdf), Corollary 4.10.

Comment: @NDB Thank you! The reference was very useful